Retry count in SmallRye on Qurkus + Java 11 application when invoking a WebService
How to count the number of retry already happen when using SmallRya on Quarkus + JDK11 based application?
My application is invoking another external webservice endpoint. I use @Retry annotation for
@Retry(maxRetries = 4, retryOn = ProcessingException.class)
@ExponentialBackoff

calling the method if the external webservice didn't return 200 as a response status. My retry count is 4. I have to return null if I didn't receive response status=200 after 4 times. In Java, SmallRye, how can I handle this?

If you want to invoke the method 4 times at most, set maxRetries to 3 (1 initial attempt + 3 retries). Then, add a @Fallback (with the same applyOn as @Retry.retryOn) that will return null. Retry is nested inside fallback, so if retry fails, fallback will apply.
